# How to get top 5 selected items with mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table 
**submitted_answers** and a table **answers**

in **submitted_answers** I have *id*, and *ans* field
*ans* is a varchar(255) field that contains comma delimited data such as "18,19,20,22,23,25"

all those numbers are correlated to *ids* in **answers** table
Example table structure

```
submitted_answers
id (int)    ans(varchar(255))
1           "18, 19"
2           "21, 22"

answers
id  ans
18  "Money"
19  "Gold"
20  "Whatever"
21  "Whatever2"
```

How can i join these table and see which top 5 items appear the most in **submitted_answers**.*ans* field.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: So what is common link between 2 tables?

Comment: What are your primary and foreign keys? Also can you explain about your table structures?

Comment: The common link is ids in submitted_answers ans link to ids in answer table. I just not sure how to extract those ids from varchar by themselves and count up which ones appear the most. I am familiar with different joins etc.

Comment: I really think your database is built poorly. It may be in your best interest to create a *third* table, which will store User ID (as a foreign key) answer_id (FK).

Comment: Comma delimited data in an RDMS is evil.... which your problem shows. There are kludges to make this work, but first of all: is normalization an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, your database structure is aweful.  You should not be representing lists of ids as comma-delimited strings in a relational database.

That said, you can do what you want with a clever use of the `on` clause:

```
select a.id, a.ans, count(*) as cnt
from submitted_answers sa join
     answers a
     on concat(', ', sa.ans, ', ') like concat('%, ', a.id, ', %')
group by a.id, a.ans
order by cnt desc
limit 5
```

Comment: I didn't come up with the structure. I agree it's not the best that's why it's hard to come up with the query for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    SELECT answer_num, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM answers 
GROUP BY answer_num 
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Working example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80a68/2

Notice the way I setup the database there, you may want to consider this type of setup for the many to many relationship of User and user answer.

Comment: Yes I understand all of that. Unfortunately I didn't set up the database and I still need to get results the right results. There is too much data for me to recreate the database.